# Bash - Check parameters established in another file

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that read a file with properties.

**Properties file**

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
param3=value3
```

**Bash**

```
file="./parameters.txt"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."

    while IFS='=' read -r key value
    do
        key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
        eval "${key}='${value}'"
    done < "$file"

else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

I want to check that each parameter is not empty.

```
if [ -z ${param1} ]
then
    echo "Param1 is empty"; exit 1
fi
```

I can check them through `if-else` but I would like to know some more dynamic way.

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way is always user dependent. But since you are using `bash`, you could use a shell parameter expansion `${!<var-name>}`.
You can also use `.` or `source` to read in the file with the variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./parameters.txt"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."

    # Read in the values from the file.
    . "${file}"

    # Iterate over the keys of the file and test if the variable contains anything.
    while read key;
    do
        # Here comes the parameter expansion. 
        if [ -z "${!key}" ]
        then
            echo "${key} is empty"
        fi
    done <<< $(cut -d '=' -f 1  parameters.txt)
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: It returns all params in one line: `param1 param2 param3 is empty`

Comment: It seems there is something wrong reading in the file. What is the output of `cut -d '=' -f 1  parameters.txt` and `wc -l parameters.txt`?

Comment: The `cut` result is: param1 param2 param3 and `wc` result is 3

Comment: Are the `cut` results newline separated or all in one line? Do you have set `IFS`? The `cut` command should return every `param*` result in a new line.

Comment: Separated line by line as I set in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

check()
{
    local file="./parameters.txt"
    local assertion var val

    while read assertion
    do
    var=${assertion/=*}
    test "${var}" != "${assertion}" || return 1
    val=${assertion#*=}
    test -n "${val}" || return 3
    done < ${file}

    return 0
}

check
```